# Java AWT - How to save images in Arraylist

Tags: java, image, arraylist, awt

I want to to save pictures in an Arraylist so that I can recall them with a variable. They should by little pictures with cards shown in a single JLabel which can be expanded any time.

I'm new to Java and can't imagine how to do this. May some of you do.

The Code on the bottom is as far as I can get and shows where the pictures should be instead of characters.

```
if (event.getSource() == bBet) {       
     random = getRandom();
     CardsPC.add(getCard(random));
     setPointsPC(random);

     String text = CardsPC.get(0);
     for(int i = 1; i < CardsPC.size(); i++){
           text = text + ", " + CardsPC.get(i);
     }
     lblCardsPC.setText(text);
}

public String[] Cards = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", **(Pictures here)**};

public String getCard(int random) {

    String card = Cards[random];
    return card;
}

public int getRandom() {
    int random = r.nextInt(13);
    return random;
} 


public void setPointsPC(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 0:
        pointsPC.add("2");
        break;
    case 1:
        pointsPC.add("3");
        break;
    case 2:
        pointsPC.add("4");
        break;
    case 3:
        pointsPC.add("5");
        break;
    case 4:
        pointsPC.add("6");
        break;
    case 5:
        pointsPC.add("7");
        break;
    case 6:
        pointsPC.add("8");
        break;
    case 7:
        pointsPC.add("9");
        break;
    case 8:
        pointsPC.add("10");
        break;
    case 9:
        pointsPC.add("10");
        break;
    case 10:
        pointsPC.add("10");
        break;
    case 11:
        pointsPC.add("10");
        break;
    case 12:
        pointsPC.add("11");
        break;
    case 13:
        pointsPC.add("-10");
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for an [Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)...

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("myFile.png"));
```

that image can be used as an [ImageIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) on Labels/Buttons or it can be drawn directly on a Graphics

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);

Graphics g = ...;
g.drawImage(img, 0,0, null);
```